# What types of nodes and management services pairs should the administrator configure for this topologywe

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

A system administrator is tasked with creating a WebSphere Application Server Network
Deployment topology with the following servers:

• a deployment manager (DMGR)
• a custom node
• an IBM HTTP Server (IHS)

What types of nodes and management services pairs should the administrator configure for this
topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 
Managed node and DMGR server
Managed node and node agent
Unmanaged node and IHS administration server

These are the different kind of profiles available in WebSphere
A node which has node agent is an managed node.
And with out a NA is unmanaged , like stand alone server. You can see **Application server profile** doesn't have a node agent.

[image]